# How to adapt this MKS Source Integrity workflow to Git?

Tags: git, version-control

Please consider the following case :

- Currently using MKS Source Integrity (yes, it hurts).
- Twice a week, some developers check in a feature (or part of it) to the development branch.

  - Check-ins for one feature get intertwined with check-ins of other features.
  - example: rev 1, 3, 5 are for feature A, rev 2 for feature B, rev 4 for feature C.
- Once a week, validated features are checked in to the production branch.

  - Most often requires to merge out changes from non-validated features.
  - example: feature A (from above) goes to production, but not feature B and C, so we wan't to take rev 1, 3, 5 (discard 2 and 4), but also, rev 3 might have required a merge with changes from rev 2 when it went in development; that merge will be undone.

Moving to Git (Yay!). What workflow would respect that constraint?

I have read a lot about it, and every workflow seems to be based on the assumption that at a time t, feature A, B, and C will be done. If not, I guess t is delayed.

In my case, there is no rush for finishing features in time, ever. Each developer works on one or several features. If it's ready, it goes to production. If it's not, keep refining. Every week, a production build happens. Extremely rarely, there is no new code changes going to production, but it's built anyways. Most often a dozen features go in production.

Hope it's clear enough. Let me know if you need more details!

(EDIT) Workflow considered:

1. Work on feature in private branch
2. Push for the first time to development, as one single commit
3. Continue work in private branch
4. Push some more changes to development, still as one single commit
5. Feature is ready for production; merge private branch with production branch

Rebase workflow:

At step 2, the private branch could be rebased on the latest development head, before the push. But doing so, what would happen when rebasing again at step 4? All the changes from the first rebase, now part of development, would be stripped out of the newly rebased private branch, wouldn't they? This would create a problem when going in production.

Merge workflow:

At step 2, the private branch could be merged with the latest development head;

- the merge commit could be discarded in the private branch, keeping the private branch untouched by what happens in the development branch. But doing so, one would have to do the same merges again and again, every time something is checked in development.
- the merge commit could be kept, and pushing to development would only require to merge with what is new since last check-in. But when going to production, the private branch would now carry changes from other features. Cherry-picking could be used to pick only the relevant change sets, but this would require the developer to manually decide what check-ins go and is prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would put each feature into it's own branch (taking full advantage of Git's light weight branches). Once the feature is ready, master can be merged into the feature branch, the feature can be verified, then the branch can be merged into master (or production, or whatever :)).

The other addition I would use here, is to have the developers push to their own remote repo's, and then have 1 person in charge of pulling changes from the developer's remote repo's into the main "blessed" repository. This helps maintain control and "purity" of the blessed repository.

Comment: I have used Git and understand how it works, at least to some extent. The feature branch is definitely something I would use. I am not sure of the best way to properly maintain that feature branch though. Since there will be several pushes to the development branch during its lifetime, and possibly several merges/conflicts, when that feature branch is finally ready, it could contains parts of some not-yet-ready features.

Comment: Each feature should have it's own feature branch. Only ready features go into the root branch (development or master), and the feature branches merge the root branch into them (not vice versa) to keep up to date. When a feature is complete, delete the branch so it isn't a maintenance headache

Comment: Yes, each feature has its own branch. But a developer cannot completely test his own private branch, because there are too many tests, dealing with tons of different DBMS, and it would be a nightmare to keep every developer's clients up to date. So, to test changes made in a private feature branch, the changes must, every so often, be integrated into the development branch, with other developers' changes.